# Cannot access php mysqli connection object property

Tags: php, mysqli, database-connection, last-insert-id

I have a connection class and it connects to the desired db table successfully. I have performed an insert query and i want to get the last inserted id of the connection. But I get a `Notice: Undefined property: connection::$insert_id` error. I `var_dump($con)` on connection object and following is what i get. Hope someone can help me to get this solved. Your help is much appreciated.

> object(connection)#2 (5) { ["db_name"]=> string(5) "dbproject" ["db_user"]=> string(4) "root" ["db_pass"]=> string(0) "" ["db_host"]=> string(9) "localhost" ["connection"]=> object(mysqli)#3 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 241ae00989d1995ffcbbf63d579943635faf9972 $" ["client_version"]=> int(50012) ["connect_errno"]=> int(0) ["connect_error"]=> NULL ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["host_info"]=> string(20) "localhost via TCP/IP" ["info"]=> NULL ["insert_id"]=> int(26) ["server_info"]=> string(21) "5.5.5-10.1.19-MariaDB" ["server_version"]=> int(50505) ["stat"]=> string(136) "Uptime: 302248 Threads: 1 Questions: 9631 Slow queries: 0 Opens: 65 Flush tables: 1 Open tables: 40 Queries per second avg: 0.031" ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["protocol_version"]=> int(10) ["thread_id"]=> int(522) ["warning_count"]=> int(0) } }

```
class connection {

    public $db_name;
    public $db_user;
    public $db_pass;
    public $db_host;

    public $connection;

     public function connection(){
        $this->db_host = HOST;
        $this->db_user = DB_USERNAME;
        $this->db_pass = DB_PASSWORD;
        $this->db_name = DB_NAME;

        $this->connection = new mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
    }

    function connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name) {

        $this->connection = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db_name);

        if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
            printf("Connection failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        return $this->connection;

    }

    public function query($sql)
        {
        return $this->connection->query($sql);
        }

   }

//--------

require_once("connection.php");

class DB {

    public $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new connection();
    }

    function insertQuery($table, $data_array){ 

        $fields = " (";
        $values = " VALUES (";
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;

        foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {

            $fields.= $key;
            $values.= "'".addslashes($value)."'";

            if(sizeof($data_array)-1 != $x){
                $fields.= ",";
                $values.=",";
            }
            else{
                $fields.= ")";
                $values.=")";
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "insert into ".$table.$fields.$values;

        if (!$this->con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            return "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $this->con->error;
        }
        else {
            $last_id = $this->con->insert_id;
            return $last_id;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "connection::$insert_id" sounds wrong (Declared as 'static'?). I think you had better show how you are calling your class and inserting the data. ($conection->insert_id; sounds better.)

Comment: Yeah I know. I added my DB class as well.

Comment: Your connection() function within connection class isn't being called. "public function connection()" should be "public function __construct()" as well.

Comment: Hi, I removed mysqli connection statement from the constructor. included it in the the connect() method using defined variables of the class and calling it like; `$dbConnection = new connection();
        $this->con = $dbConnection->connect();`  worked. I have no idea why the same thing on the constructor acted weird. Any explanations?

Answer (score -2):

In `DB` class constructor first you should have set credential properties (`db_host, db_user, db_pass, db_name`) and call `connection` method of `connection` class

```
class DB {

    public $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new connection();
        $this->con->db_host = HOST; // replace HOST
        $this->con->db_user = DB_USERNAME; // replace DB_USERNAME
        $this->con->db_pass = DB_PASSWORD; // replace DB_PASSWORD
        $this->con->db_name = DB_NAME; // replace DB_NAME
        $this->con->connection();
    }

    function insertQuery($table, $data_array){ 

        $fields = " (";
        $values = " VALUES (";
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;

        foreach ($data_array as $key => $value) {

            $fields.= $key;
            $values.= "'".addslashes($value)."'";

            if(sizeof($data_array)-1 != $x){
                $fields.= ",";
                $values.=",";
            }
            else{
                $fields.= ")";
                $values.=")";
            }
            $x++;
        }

        $sql = "insert into ".$table.$fields.$values;

        if (!$this->con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            return "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $this->con->error;
        }
        else {
            $last_id = $this->con->insert_id;
            return $last_id;
        }
    }
 }
```